# Error grouping rows with similar ids together

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to group rows with similar ids (order_id in this case) together. I want each group of similar ids in a separate table. My presence query displays all rows in one table. I don't know how to go about it.

This is my code:

```
<div class='panel panel-body'>
          <table class='table table-condensed'>
              <thead>
                  <tr class='cart_menu'>
                      <td class='price'>Order ID</td>
                      <td class='price'>Item(s)</td>
                      <td class='price'>Quantity</td>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              ";

              $select = "SELECT DISTINCT a.*, b.* FROM shipping_order a JOIN shipping_details b ON b.order_id = a.order_id WHERE user_id = :user_id AND a.order_id = b.order_id";
              foreach ($db->query($select, array('user_id' => $id)) AS $items){

              echo"
              <tr>
                  <td class='cart_price'>
                      <h4>{$items['order_id']}</h4>
                  </td>
                  <td class='cart_price'>
                      <h4><a href=''>{$items['item']}</a></h4>
                      <!-- <p>Web ID: </p> -->
                  </td>
                  <td class='cart_price'>
                      <p>{$items['quantity']}</p>
                  </td>
              </tr>

              ";
              }
              echo"
              {$items['total']}
              </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: When you say "rows with similar ids", what do you mean? How are they similar and how should they be grouped?

Comment: Remove all this code. Instead provide proper create and insert statements AND a desired result.